# Political candidate's stances on specific issues?

Tags: government, politics

I believe that a large percentage of the US population are politically unaware and tend to vote on the candidate whom they 'like' the most. It would be great if public can have easy access to view each issue and each candidates stance on it.

Comment: What is your **data request**? Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) an [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to gauge a politician’s stance is based on the sources of their donations.

https://www.followthemoney.org

https://classic.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/norindsea.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea of where they stand via voting from [govtrack](https://www.govtrack.us/) and [open states](https://openstates.org/) APIs.